# Proving that $\sum_j x^j$ is differentiable $(-1,1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm really struggling with understanding how to apply the Weierstrass M-test, and so some hints on this question would be much appreciated:

First I want to prove that $\sum_{j = 0}^\infty x^j$ is differentiable on $(-1,1)$. I don't think I can use the fact that for $|x|<1$, $\sum_j x^j = {1\over 1-x}$ and just take the difference quotient to get $(\sum_j x^j)' = {1\over 1- 2x + x^2}$.

And I'm not sure how to show that 
$$
{\mathrm d \over \mathrm d x} \sum_{j = 0}^\infty x^j = \sum_{j = 0}^\infty (j+1)x^j
$$

Any hints would be much appreciated. Cheers

### Answer Attempt

By the ratio test, 
$$
\limsup {|a_{j+1}| \over |a_j|} = \limsup |{j+2\over j+1} \cdot x| = |x| < 1
$$
therefore for any fixed $x$ the series converges absolutely, and since $x \in (-1,1)$ was arbitrary, we see that $\sum_j (j+1)x^j$ converges uniformly on $(-1,1)$, and therefore we have a series of functions $\sum_j f'_j$ which converges uniformly, and so we may apply the theorem mentioned in the comments

Comment: Do you know the theorem that if $\{f_j\}$ is a sequence of differentiable functions converging to $f$ and $f'_j$ converges uniformly to $g$ then $f$ is differentiable and $f'=g$?

Comment: Yes but I am not sure how to show that $\sum_j (j+1)x^j$ converges to a finite number for $|x| < 1$?

Comment: Use the ratio test, knowing that $\sum x^j$ converges for $|x|<1.$ You need to show uniform convergence, but a power series converges uniformly on compact subsets of its domain of convergence.

Comment: Close. We don't know that it converges uniformly on $(-1,1)$, but it does converge uniformly on *compact subsets* of $(-1,1)$. Since every point in $(-1,1)$ is contained in a compact subset, you can justify term-by-term differentiation everywhere on $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Ah, so it converges on every interval $[-\beta, \beta]$ for $|\beta| < 1$? Many thanks for your help @EricAuld

Comment: Right, exactly. You're very welcome.

Comment: To be precise, it converges *uniformly* on $[-\beta,\beta]$, although it converges pointwise on $(-1,1)$ (and we can check whether it does on the endpoints too).

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to show that the serie
$$
\sum_{ j =0}^ \infty (j+1) x^j 
$$
converges uniformly for all compacts of $(-1, 1)$
and 
$$
\sum_{j = 0} ^\infty x^j
$$
converges simplely in $(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, we can use the convergence properties of  Taylor series to guarantee that term-by-term differentiation applies.  Each term of the series is differentiable, with continuous derivative. Also, a Taylor series converges uniformly within its radius of convergence.